# Azure Custom Extensions Blob return 403 Forbidden

Tags: azure, storage, azure-rm-template, azureportal, azure-vm-scale-set

I've tried to run a custom script to install software silently to my Windows Scaleset
Here is my configurations
Arm template added to virtualMachineProfile like child resource to ExtensionProfile here is the code

```
 {   
       "name": "InstallSomeCoolStuffs",
        "properties":{
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.10",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {},
        "protectedSettings": {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File myscript.ps1",
        "managedIdentity": {},
        "fileUris": ["https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/src/myscript.ps1"
          ]
       }
   }
},
```

The problem was when I tried to Deploy the ARM template with enabled managed identity and add Contributor role to Storage Account failed with message:

```
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'MyScript'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "
```

1. Tried to move fileUris to **Settings section** same error.
2. Different typeHandlerVersion 1.19,1.10,1.17.
3. Tried to add {objectID:} ScaleSet identity id
   It works only if remove managed identity and add **StoraceAccountName: StorageAccountKey:**
   What I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution if someone gets the same problem.

1. Make sure in the **settings** section is added **fileUris** and timestamp, timestamp is something like versioning on your script, every time you pass a larger integer will create a new version and trigger the script and you can check the output to  Windows VM  C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.2\Status
2. Make sure you add a **Storage Blob Data Reader** Role Assignment to scaleset identity